# Using ImportHTML or ImportXML to Select Non-Consecutive Columns In Google Sheets, Remove Rows, & Add A Sort Column

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I am wanting to import the table information from [https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/draft.htm](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/draft.h) into a google sheet. However, I'm trying to avoid pulling in null cells as well as information I already have in other sheets. Here are my questions:

1. The only columns I want are Round (col1), Pick (Col2), and Player (Col4). I've tried using ImportHTML and so far, all i can do is grab the whole table.
2. I want to create a new column called 'Rd.Pick' which would convert the pick column into a representation ofwhat pick in the respective round they were. So aka Pick 33 would display 2.1
3. Finally, I would like to be able to remove the rows that are listed in between the last pick of a round but before the first pick in the following round. I'm not sure how to do that given that the text in those rows matches the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to answer the question from your comment above - how to convert the sequential draft pick number to a number like 3.12, 12th pick in the 3rd round.
This formula is a bit brute force, but it works:

```
={"Round-Pick";
ArrayFormula(ifna(ifs(
  D2:D=1,"1."& text(E2:E,"00"),
  D2:D=2,"2."& text(E2:E-max(filter(D$2:E,D$2:D=1)),"00"),
  D2:D=3,"3."& text(E2:E-max(filter(D$2:E,D$2:D=2)),"00"),
  D2:D=4,"4."& text(E2:E-max(filter(D$2:E,D$2:D=3)),"00"),
  D2:D=5,"5."& text(E2:E-max(filter(D$2:E,D$2:D=4)),"00"),
  D2:D=6,"6."& text(E2:E-max(filter(D$2:E,D$2:D=5)),"00"),
  D2:D=7,"7."& text(E2:E-max(filter(D$2:E,D$2:D=6)),"00")
  ),""))}
```

If you put that in NFLDraft!F1, it should do what you want.  You could then hide Column E if you like.

UPDATED: To provide the format you've requested, with leading zero.
[image]

Comment: this is fantastic! so i played around with it some to try and learn what it's doing but clearly flubbed ....... how would you get the format to go from 1.1 and 1.2 to 1.01 and 1.02 without making it also go to 1.010 and such? If that can't be done no problem just trying to see how the numbers are processed here.

 Any thoughts on how to remove rows with PLAYER,PLAYER,player in cols A/B/C respectively?

Comment: Okay, I updated your NFLDraft tab here, to give you the formatting you're asking for:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VUTdh6FMYrs4SL1bhNIVIDrgoSXBbZMxBkd-_RAuSP8/edit#gid=1489095038&range=F1

Comment: Also, removed the blank rows between rounds.  Added this to the query that player0 gave you: `and Col1 <> 'Player'` .  This just excludes the header rows that are placed in the website's HTML source table, between rounds.   Player0 did the hard part in providing your answer, so if this is doing what you want, you can check off his answer.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/draft.htm", 
 "table", 1), "select Col4"), 
 QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/draft.htm", 
 "table", 1), "select Col1")&"."&
 QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/draft.htm", 
 "table", 1), "select Col2")}, "where not Col2 matches '\.'", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! can help me tweak it as i might have not stated things clearly in my initial post
i replaced &"."& with just a comma so everything is in its own column.

What i'd like in column D now is similar to what you did merging Rnd & Pick but i was hoping to create a scale that converts pick 33 to 2.1 (as it is the first pick in the second round). and thus pick 65 would be come 3.1. A few notes on that though as there is not always the same number of picks in each round. Lastly, is there a way to remove the rows that simply say "player" in them... eg Row 34

Comment: @InStackOfHelp, See answer below to modify the format of your draft pick numbers.